# Need to display data on a jsp page using struts 1.3

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I am trying to read data from a table and display it to the user .

Can anybody tell how to do it using struts 1.3 ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Write an class  extending Struts' `Action` class. This class pulls the data from Database as a `List`. Pass this data as request attribute, `request.setAttribute("myList", list)`. Return "success".
2. In your `struts-config.xml`, map this `Action` class to a JSP on "success". The request will be forwarded to the JSP.
3. In the JSP, get the list from request by `request.getAttribute("myList")`. Iterate through the list and print the `List`.

You need to study this: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/index.html

Comment: I am using a HashMap to store the data from a row . Then i am adding this HashMap to an ArrayList . How to iterate the ArrayList Of HashMaps in my jsp page using <logic:iterate > ??

Answer (score 0):

(Edit:  Just noticed this is a 2 year old question)

Don't use the struts tags unless you NEED to.  This can be accomplished with jstl/el.
So on your Action class you would have something like this:

```
List<Map<?, ?>> listOfHashMaps = new ArrayList<Map<?, ?>>();
request.setAttribute("listOfHashMaps", listOfHashMaps);
```

In your jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="hashMap" items="listOfHashMaps">
    ${hashMap[someInteger]} <%-- To get the value associated with 'key' --%>
</c:forEach>
```

You can also access the keys/values with:

```
${hashMap.key}
${hashMap.value}
```

Respectively.